# Проблема с .htacess: не могу настроить редирект

Tags: php, url, get

Добрый вечер.
Друзья, помогите решить задачу: хочу переделать урлы следующего типа:

```
http://site.com/user?id=1
```

на урлы такого типа:

```
http://site.com/user/1
```

В HTACESS прописал такое:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\?id
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\?id$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Но не ничего не дает :( Помогите разобраться, заранее спасибо!

**UP:**
Вот этим кодом

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ user.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Смог добиться того, что урл стал такого вида:

```
http://site.com/1
```

где "1" это id, которое успешно передается по $_GET['id'], но мне нужно сделать урл такой:

```
http://site.com/user/1
```

То есть дописать перед "1" еще user/
Помогите :)

Comment: Вы точно хотите сделать так, чтобы пользователь переходил по ссылке или вводил в адресную строку `http://site.com/user?id=1` (и видел там именно это) а Апач передавал в скрипт (или сам обрабатывал) запрос `http://site.com/user/1`?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы при переходе по ссылке вида http://site.com/user?id=1 производился автоматический редирект на урл такого вида http://site.com/user/1 При этом "1" должна восприниматься параметром $_GET, чтобы я мог на странице user.php получить id пользователя так: $user_id = $_GET['id']

Answer (score 1):

Не дает потому что в документации по-английски написано:

> ...the Pattern is matched against only a partial path...
>
> If you wish to match against the ... query string, use a RewriteCond with the ... %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively

Перевожу на человеческий: Выражение сравнивается только с частью пути не затрагивая GET-параметры. Если вам очень нужно заменять именно вместе с параметрами запроса - придется использовать RewriteCond.

Однако в целом ваш случай пока не очень понимаю. Мне кажется что вы неправильно сформулировали для себя задачу.

На всякий случай могу предложить такое решение (ну вдруг и правда так надо)

```
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^user/?$ /user/%1
```

Эти строки будут искать запросы с GET-параметром id и переписывать их если
запрос совпадает с `user`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user?id=$1 [L]
```

прописываем user.php чтоб переходил на /user/blabla

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^user$ /user/%1? [L]
```

надеюсь что помог

Comment: Спасибо! Но увы... не помогает.

Comment: в чем проблема? почему не работает?

Comment: Не знаю, какой бы урл не ввел, редирект не срабатывает.  Но у меня еще такое прописано в htacess: # browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

Answer (score 0):

Редирект (с `RewriteCond` знаком с чужих слов, так что с его синтаксисом мог накосячить, [но за регулярки уверен](https://regex101.com/r/4pwlff/3)):

```
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} ^id=([1-9][0-9]*)(?:&([a-z\-_]+=[a-z0-9\-_]+))$
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-_]+)(?:\.php)$ $1/%1?%2 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} ^id=([1-9][0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-_]+)(?:\.php)$ $1/%1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-_]+)(?:\.php)$ $1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Второй рерайт должен сработать, если иных параметров, кроме `id` не передано, а третий просто заменяет адреса вида `user.php` на `user/`, если они введёны без параметров.

Рерайт ([что делает](https://regex101.com/r/4pwlff/6)). Добавил параметр `rewritten=1`, чтобы запросы, посланные сервером, не попадали под редирект, иначе будет бесконечное перенаправление:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-_]+)(?:(?:\/([1-9][0-9]*))?)$ $1.php?rewritten=1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```